# Pull Value from String using Regular Expressions and store as a new column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I have a SQL Server stored procedure where I feed the value 'Mat' which may contain at the end of the value: (DAY), (MONTH), (HR)

If this value exists, I want to be able to pull it out using a regular expression or another way if easier and store it as another column.

I have currently tried using the `LIKE` operation in SQL Server to have as a new column but I don't believe SQL Server allows this.

Here is my current stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateMaterial_Get_MaterialValues_ByMaterialName]
--UpdateMaterial_Get_MaterialValues_ByMaterialName '2 Inch Discharge Hose (DAY)'
--UpdateMaterial_Get_MaterialValues_ByMaterialName '2 Step Hydroseeding'
    @MAT NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        DEFAULTS.Mat, DEFAULTS.Region, DEFAULTS.MatUnit, DEFAULTS.MatWidth,
        TYPEDESC.TypeDesc AS MatType,
        @MAT LIKE '(\S+)' AS EquipmentType
    FROM 
        tbl_MaterialDefaults DEFAULTS 
    RIGHT JOIN
        tbl_Client_List_Type_Desc TYPEDESC ON TYPEDESC.Num = DEFAULTS.MatID
    WHERE 
        Mat = @MAT
END
```

Currently I get an error when trying to execute the `ALTER`:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'like'.

You can see the two examples in the code of what the @MAT value could be. Here would be my expected for the two:

For @MAT value '2 Inch Discharge Hose (DAY)'

```
Mat                            Region                       MatUnit   MatWidth  MatType   EquipmentType      
2 Inch Discharge Hose (DAY)    Standard Sacramento          ACRE      1.00      MATERIAL  (DAY)
```

For @MAT value '2 Step Hydroseeding'

```
Mat                            Region                       MatUnit   MatWidth  MatType   EquipmentType
2 Step Hydroseeding            Standard Sacramento          ACRE      1.00      MATERIAL
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  Also, on a personal note, I have always been of the opinion that a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` is usually easier to understand as a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` when put in the proper order.

Comment: SQL Server Version: 12.0.5207.0,  I will double check where I need to ignore NULLS.  Thanks for that tip.

Comment: You can't use `LIKE` in a `SELECT`. You may be able to do what you're trying with a `CASE/WHEN`.

Comment: How does `2 Step Hydroseeding` relate to your example? What is in the `MAT` column? Are you able to provide a sample fiddle or some data?

Comment: I edited the post to show the Mat within now so you can get a better idea how it is involved.

Comment: Are there ever parenthesis in `Mat` values prior to the suffix you're trying to parse out?

Comment: No, that is the only time they occur.  EDIT:  Sorry no it can occur before.  This is the only other case where it exists:  Mat = 'Installed (Photo Net) Curlex Blanket'

Comment: What calls this stored procedure? Another stored procedure? Code? Since you're passing in the information (the `@MAT` value) that includes the information you intend to return (`Equipment Type`), can't you simply parse it out in code?

Comment: @AnnL. Yes I pass the Mat value from a program that runs the query.  But it is not parsed from the beginning.  This Mat value is being pulled from a list of Materials in another DB Table.

Comment: At any point prior to calling this stored proc, do you have the Equipment Type as a separate piece of information, not appended onto `@Mat`?  Because if you know both of them before calling the stored procedure, you could pass them as separate parameters, rather than concatenating them.

Comment: @AnnL. No.  It starts out from creation of the Mat name by the users as this.  Though it may be easier at this point to build in the start a separation so it may be used in the manner you are referring.

Comment: Since these are essentially two different pieces of data, building them separate from the start would be far easiest. That string _can_ be stripped out with regular SQL, but a CLR function would probably be much easier for this. SQL "Regex" is somewhat limited.

Comment: In my experience, "hybrid data" (one piece of data that contains two or more pieces of information) will tie you in absolute knots if you let it into your system. What if someone tells you they want material names sorted by equipment type? What would you do in that case?

Comment: Trust me: your life, and the life of every programmer after you who has to work with this system, will be much simpler if you can force "equipment type" to be stored as an attribute of a material, but NOT part of its name or ID. It's a lot easier to always DISPLAY an attribute with a name than it is to store it as PART of the name but sometimes pretend it's a separate attribute!

Comment: "hybrid data" < I like that. And yes, it will 100% tie you in knots.

Comment: "and the life of every programmer after you who has to work with this system"  < That is a huge thing to keep in mind when writing any system. And in that batch of programmers, I would also include "you + 6 months".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

Within your stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @ExprStart int = -1,
        @ExprEnd int = -1,
        @EquipmentType varchar(100) = NULL

IF @Mat LIKE '%(%)%' BEGIN
  SET @ExprStart = PATINDEX('%)%', REVERSE(@Mat)),
      @ExprEnd = PATINDEX('%(%', REVERSE(@Mat))
  SET @EquipmentType = REVERSE(SUBSTRING( @Mat, @ExprStart, @ExprEnd - @ExprStart + 1 ))
END

SELECT 
    DEFAULTS.Mat, 
    DEFAULTS.Region, 
    DEFAULTS.MatUnit, 
    DEFAULTS.MatWidth,
    TYPEDESC.TypeDesc AS MatType,
    @EquipmentType AS EquipmentType
 FROM 
    tbl_MaterialDefaults DEFAULTS 
 RIGHT JOIN
    tbl_Client_List_Type_Desc TYPEDESC ON TYPEDESC.Num = DEFAULTS.MatID
 WHERE 
    Mat = @MAT
```

This will work if - and only if - you NEVER have any parentheses before the Equipment Type at the end. But I believe you said that was the case.

EDITED TO ADD:  I see that you've since said that earlier parentheses CAN happen. I have adjusted the code to accommodate that.  My new version assumes that we are pulling the FINAL set of parentheses from `@Mat`.

EDITED TO ADD AN EVEN SIMPLER VERSION:  If you've ONLY got `(HR)`, `(DAY)`, and `(MONTH)` to worry about, we can do this:

```
 -- We don't need any of those declarations or PATINDEXes.
 SELECT 
     DEFAULTS.Mat, 
     DEFAULTS.Region, 
     DEFAULTS.MatUnit, 
     DEFAULTS.MatWidth,
     TYPEDESC.TypeDesc AS MatType,
     CASE WHEN RTRIM(@Mat) LIKE '%(HR)'
          THEN '(HR)'
          WHEN RTRIM(@Mat) LIKE '%(DAY)'
          THNE '(DAY)'
          WHEN RTRIM(@Mat) LIKE '%(MONTH)'
          THEN '(MONTH)'
     END AS EquipmentType
 FROM etc.
```

BUT, this works only for as long as you ONLY have those strings. I am also assuming they will ALWAYS be at the end, and that only white space (which can be stripped by `RTRIM()` can come after them.

Comment: Sorry I edited my reply after I posted but this isn't the case sometimes.  Here was the example I used:  'Installed (Photo Net) Curlex Blanket'  This example would be ignored.  The Cases though where I dont ignore will always be, (DAY), (MONTH), (HR)  These could be used in the same style as you have shown where I look for either of those and set the column EquipmentType based on the result.

Comment: Oh!  Then this can be a lot simpler!  I'll add the simpler query!

Comment: That's an elegant use of `REVERSE`. I think I'd use that to guard against the future creation of additional codes that incorporate parenthesis earlier in the string. +1

Comment: Amazing thank you.  Right Trim I wasn't aware of and that case use will work perfectly for this scenario.  I agree with @EricBrandt.  That previous use of `REVERSE` is awesome.